# EF: using backing field for setting property value

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm

Is there a way to make EF use backing field when setting the values of property instead of property setter?

The reason I'm asking is that in setter there might be a logic that I don't want to be called every time an object is returned from database.

For ex:

```
class SomeClass
{
    int _prop;

    public Prop
    {
        get { return _prop;}
        set 
        {
            CustomValidation(value);

            _prop = value; 
        }
    }  
}
```

In the above sample, CustomValidation() is called on setting the value. There is no need to call this validation when returning objects from db, since those objects were validated on creation/validation.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently you can't map the column directly to a field. It has been discussed last year, but I'm not sure whether this will be part of future release or not. Check this [article](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20-%20February%2020%2C%202013) for further explanation. This is the code excerpt of the design.

> ```
> modelBuilder
>    .Entity<Blog>()
>    .Property(b => b.Title)
>    .UseBackingField("_theTitle");
> ```

The workaround would be creating a domain object or adding unmapped property that will be used in the front end for creation or validation.

```
public int Prop { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public int ValidatedProp // bind to this property in the front end
{
   get { return Prop; } 
   set 
   {
       CustomValidation(value);
       Prop = value;
   }
}
```